# How to classify documents with stanford NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to classify news documents on the basis of type of content it has. For example, Sports, Politics, Entertainment etc. How i can do this using stanford- nlp? If possible, please share an example for the same.

Comment: saxena, welcome to stackoverflow. In this website people solve questions of a specific problem you have while coding, this means that we expect you to have read at least the basic tutorial and have already an example yourself (even if it's not working). I'm sorry, but this website was not designed to provide tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

This link should be of interest:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/classifier.shtml